# I need to cache XML data and upload it when iPhone is back in coverage area

Tags: iphone, ios, caching, upload

In my app i have two textfields and a submit button.

Clicking on submit will upload the data to a web server in the form of an XML.

This is fairly simple, but what i want is that if the phone is out of coverage the app should cache the data and send it automatically when the user is back in the coverage area.

How to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go look on the Apple developer site for the Reachability example. This will show you how to detect when data connection changes availability. Try sending and if sending fails, save the file locally and then you can just try resending it when it signals that you have data connection again.

You should look at this anyway if you are using data connection as it is something that is in the Apple guidelines that you should support in your app if it is using a data connection and your app can get rejected if you don't handle losing data connection.